# Find out the class of an object in prototypejs

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs, prototype

I use prototypejs Class API for class-based OOP.

Is there a way to get the class name of an an object?

EG:

```
var myDog = new Dog();
myDog.getClassName() //Should return "Dog"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Prototypejs' [`create()`](http://prototypejs.org/api/class/create) function to create the class, you need to store an additional property to hold the name of the class, since the only *reference* to a class named `Dog` is the variable name to which you assign the result of `create()`:

```
var Dog = Class.create({
  className: "Dog",

  initialize: function() {
  }
});

var myDog = new Dog();
console.log(myDog.className); // "Dog"
```

On the other hand, if you are defining your class with something along these lines:

```
function Dog() {
}
```

Then, you could just use [`Object#constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```
myDog.constructor.name; // "Dog"
```

Comment: In that case, `Dog` is just the name of the variable. I don't think you'll be able to get its name without extending the object returned by Prototypejs.

Comment: is there another way to define a class, which saves the name of the class in the object?

Comment: @indieman: Yes, initialize it with `Class.create({ className: "Dog", initialize: ...`. And then, access the class name with `myDog.className`. Here's a DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ZwKNU/.